# Why won't my shell pipeline run on my server with a private runner? Why do i get this error message?

Tags: github, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to make a ci pipeline which executes commands via the shell on an ubuntu sever and I have setup a private runner dedicated to this with the shell execution mode. But whenever I try to run a pipeline, I get this error message:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 11.2.0 (11.2.0)
  on gitlab-runner V65mu6qL
Using Shell executor...
Running on flask-server...
bash: line 71: cd: /var/lib/gitlab-runner/builds/V65mu6qL/0/1Blademaster/Flask-App: No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

How would I fix this error? I've tried making a dir in that location but that doesn't fix anything